# Should I save JSON data inside a .json file, or is it okay to save it inside a .js file?

Tags: javascript, json, nuxt.js

I have JSON data in my Nuxt project that needs to be hardcoded inside the project for some reason.
The data is not just a few lines so I'm considering storing it in a different file.

Should I save it inside a .json file, or is it okay to save it inside a .js file?

Is there anything I should consider before choosing between those 2 file types.?

Comment: doesnt matter. The only difference is that, unlike json, js you can make runtime computations if you need. But as u said, that's not the case. And of course, consider that's two different file types: one is intended to be a raw data file, in the other side we have .js file that stores a variable, module, whatever, which is a simple object.

Comment: I'd keep the data in a different file, and the JS logic in other file(s)

Comment: You can also have comments in JS files. Maybe there is a parsing time difference, you could check that one if you plan on having HUGE files. Mostly meaningless difference IMO.